# How do I get data of last few days, weeks, months, years in mongodb for admin dashboard?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, dashboard

I have an order collection. I want to get order data of the last 7 days, last 7 weeks, last 7 months and last 7 years. For example, if today is Tuesday, I want to know how many orders did I have on tuesday, how many orders on monday and similarly all days until last tuesday. Similarly I want data for all units I mentioned above. How do I achieve this?

I tried using $addFields with $dayOfTheYear, $week, $month and then grouping it inside facet pipeline accordingly but I ran into some issues cause I can only go within a year. I want a better, more straight forward method that just gives me the result of last 7 units without restriction of current year.

Comment: Did you check [$dateSubtract](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateSubtract/)?